# python formattng output with input

Tags: python-3.x

Just started programming in python 3 and I am trying to pull from an input() where I have placed the input() command in the first line and then further down use the output() to retrieve the input().

Here is an example:

```
rent = eval(input("How much does rent cost per year? $"))
```

Now I want to get the input I put in (10,000) and retrieve it from the input automatically using output() or another command.

```
print output("The family rent is", _______ , "per year."
```

What code would go in the ________ so I can retrieve what I put in for the input?

Thanks - newbie

Comment: OH please, please don't ever use `eval`. Especially not directly on user input!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Comment: I searched all over and didn't see the answer. I looked at your possible duplicate @DeepSpace and get a better understanding but not the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks for editing and clarifying the eval( command. I built up a huge code writing more detailed eval( and using arithmetic, but since I got 3 negative votes, I cant ask questions for several days. Wish I could pm you but its blocked. Thanks for all  your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code as is :

```
# get user input
user_input = input("How much does rent cost per year? $")
# cast to int or whaterver you're expecting
try :
    cost = int(user_input)
except :
    print ("expecting a number") 
    # stop here maybe return
# print output
print ("The family rent is", cost , "per year.")
```

Comment: I haven't used the int() yet, and when I added it in, it works. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use string formatting:

`print('The family rent is {} per year'.format(rent))`

See here for documentation of string formatting:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Comment: I want to use the input() so when I print it will prompt for the input with the question.
Then after the input is put in (example 10,000) , I want to be able to retrieve the exact input I put in (10,000) to be recalled in an ouput()..

Thanks.

Comment: The input function returns exactly what you entered (as a string), so in your code above the variable `rent` will contain your input. You can then pass `rent` to any function to use it, work with it, print it out or whatever. Is that what you're looking for?